# NullPointer exception on call to (.write socket data)

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, irc

I'm writing a simple IRC bot to try to learn more about Clojure, using standard Java sockets and a loop to read/parse the data, but I get a nullpointer when I attempt to send the JOIN message after the MOTD end message for some reason.

Here's my code..

```
(use 'clojure.java.io
'[clojure.string :as s :only (split)])

(def sock (java.net.Socket. "iris.archivesmc.com" 6667))

(def write-stream (writer sock))
(def read-stream  (reader sock))

(defn write [message]
    (.write write-stream (str message "\r\n"))
    (println (str "-> " message))
    (.flush write-stream)
)

(defn parseMessage [buffer]
    (if
        (= (apply str (take-last 2 buffer)) "\r\n" )
        (do
            (let [parts (split buffer #"\s")]
                (println (s/replace buffer "\r\n" ""))
                (when
                    (= (first parts) "PING")
                    ;; We need to PONG to this or we'll ping out
                    (write (str "PONG " (second parts)))
                )
                (when
                    (= (apply str(take 1 (first parts))) ":" )
                    ;; Message with a numerical prefix
                    ;; :server numeric our-nick message
                    (
                        (if
                            (= (second parts) "376")
                            ;; MOTD end
                            ;; Join #clojure
                            (write "JOIN #clojure") ;; This errors for some reason
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            ""
        )
        buffer
    )
)

(defn readLoop []
    (loop [buffer ""]
        ;;(println (str "Looping.. -> " buffer))
        (let [nbuf (parseMessage buffer)
              nchr (.read read-stream)  ]
            (if-not (= nchr -1)
                (recur (str nbuf (char nchr)))
            )
        )
    )
)

(write "NICK gClojureTestBot")
(write "USER Clojure Imma Bot :Clojure Testing Bot")
(readLoop)
```

And here's my output (with traceback etc)

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7542 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/gcoles/Downloads/idea-IC-117.418/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/home/gcoles/IdeaProjects/ClojureBot/classes:/home/gcoles/clojure/clojure-1.4.0/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/home/gcoles/IdeaProjects/ClojureBot/src:/home/gcoles/IdeaProjects/ClojureBot/test:/home/gcoles/Downloads/idea-IC-117.418/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain clojure.main /home/gcoles/IdeaProjects/ClojureBot/src/main.clj
-> NICK gClojureTestBot
-> USER Clojure Imma Bot :Clojure Testing Bot
PING :5D2E1C22
-> PONG :5D2E1C22
:iris.archivesmc.com 001 gClojureTestBot :Welcome to the archivesmc.com IRC Network gClojureTestBot!~Clojure@213.190.134.190
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at user$parseMessage.invoke(main.clj:35)
    at user$readLoop.invoke(main.clj:49)
    at user$eval10.invoke(main.clj:60)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6912)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:283)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I find this odd, since previous calls to `write` are working. Then again, being a Clojure (and Java) noob, I probably did something stupid.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: In case it matters, I'm using Java 7 and Clojure 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the following block of code..

```
            (when
                (= (apply str(take 1 (first parts))) ":" )
                ;; Message with a numerical prefix
                ;; :server numeric our-nick message
                (
                    (if
                        (= (second parts) "376")
                        ;; MOTD end
                        ;; Join #clojure
                        (write "JOIN #clojure") ;; This errors for some reason
                    )
                )
            )
```

Specifically, the `()` around the `(if)` statement was doubled up. Too many brackets. Removing the extra ones fixed the problem.

Comment: You can make it harder to accidentally do this, by following the standard lisp conventions for parentheses. If no parens are ever on their own line, it's almost impossible to accidentally write ((foo bar)) instead of (foo bar), and if you do it's very noticeable and easy to fix.

Comment: @amalloy I like your answer about positioning parens, and have been told to have them trail at the end.

Comment: @amalloy Smart thinking there; I'll bear that in mind. Thanks.